# Alright you Yemenites or Mizrahim out there! Matzah Recipe?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, matzah, yemenite-temani

Looking for information on how Yemenites or other Mizrahim bake Matzah. How much flour to water, how hot does the oven get? Does it have to go to the oven within 18 minutes, or does that only matter if the flour has been left unattended and unbeaten? Do you add salt or not? Did you temper the wheat for the flour with water before milling?

Comment: Is a recipe request on topic? If it is, watch out. Because I may request one for p'tcha, among other things. I think this should go on a food forum.

Comment: i would hope it's on topic for the following reasons: #1. Baking Matzah is one of the mitzwoth. #2. It used to be practiced by everyone. #3. It has fallen out of common useage and information on how to do it is scant to nonexistent. And therefore, the only way to find a proper way to perform this miswah is to ask for the recipes or the methods of those who still have a living tradition.

Comment: @DanF, I believe recipe requests are on topic, inasmuch as I have seen others which have not been closed.

Comment: (re the above comments) http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3709

Comment: @Aaron Actually, none of the 3 reasons in your comment is a reason for it to be on-topic. The reason it is on topic is because it asks about how certain communities prepare for doing the Mitzva of eating Matzah, which is a matter of how they practice Judaism.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt See my above comment.

Comment: @DoubleAA, #1 would suffice were it true.

Comment: @msh210 Yes. But it isn't, so it doesn't.